# How to change the icon of Panel (toggleable icon) in PrimeVue Vue3 Composition Api

Tags: vuejs3, panel, primevue

[image]

//I want to change the icon i am using icon slot but it is creating another icon rather than editing that icon

I want to change the icon i am using icon slot but it is creating another icon rather than editing that icon

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please read thoroughly the [How to Ask guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then update your question with more relevant information including some code so we can see your attempt